# How can I create a GzipFile instance from the “file-like object” that urllib.urlopen() returns?

Tags: python, gzip, urllib

I’m playing around with the Stack Overflow API using Python. I’m trying to decode the gzipped responses that the API gives.

```
import urllib, gzip

url = urllib.urlopen('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/badges/name')
gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=url).read()
```

According to [the urllib2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html), `urlopen` “returns a file-like object”.

However, when I run `read()` on the GzipFile object I’ve created using it, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'tell'
```

As far as I can tell, this is coming from the object returned by `urlopen`.

It doesn’t appear to have seek either, as I get an error when I do this:

```
url.read()
url.seek(0)
```

What exactly is this object, and how do I create a functioning `GzipFile` instance from it?

Comment: `Content-Encoding: gzip` should be handled by the http library, but unfortunately it isn't. This is [issue 9500](http://bugs.python.org/issue9500) in Python's bug database, for the interested.

Comment: @Magnus: cheers, good to know it’s at least in the bug tracker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [urlopen docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) list the supported methods of the object that is returned. I recommend wrapping the object in another class that supports the methods that gzip expects.

Other option: call the read method of the response object and put the result in a [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) object (which should support all methods that gzip expects). This maybe a little more expensive though.

E.g.

```
import gzip
import json
import StringIO
import urllib

url = urllib.urlopen('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/badges/name')
url_f = StringIO.StringIO(url.read())
g = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=url_f)
j = json.load(g)
```

Comment: Wrapping it in a `StringIO` object gets past that error, but I still get an `IOError: Not a gzipped file`

Comment: @ThomasK It works find for me. Are you passing `url.read()` to the `StringIO` constructor or just `url`? The latter fails.

Comment: Excellent, cheers. Unutbu’s answer was great too, but I’ll go with this one as I’m guessing the `StringIO` solution is more backwards compatible.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without reading the entire `urlopen` response in one go?  I'm looking to use something like this in a situation where the payload of the `urlopen` is very large (GBs), so I would like to be able to use this to stream-parse as data comes in, rather than blocking on the whole http request.

Answer (score 8):

```
import urllib2
import json
import gzip
import io

url='http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/badges/name'
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
gzip_filehandle=gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(page.read()))
json_data=json.loads(gzip_filehandle.read())
print(json_data)
```

`io.BytesIO` is for Python2.6+. For older versions of Python, you could use `cStringIO.StringIO`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new update for @stefanw's answer, to whom that might think it too expensive to use that much memory.

Thanks to this article(https://www.enricozini.org/blog/2011/cazzeggio/python-gzip/, it explains why `gzip` doesn't work), the solution is to use Python3.

```
import urllib.request
import gzip

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/badges/name')
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=response) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```