# Upload to Amazon S3 using Boto3 and return public url

Tags: django-models, amazon-s3, boto3

Iam trying to upload files to s3 using Boto3 and make that uploaded file public and return it as a url.

```
class UtilResource(BaseZMPResource):
class Meta(BaseZMPResource.Meta):
    queryset = Configuration.objects.none()
    resource_name = 'util_resource'
    allowed_methods = ['get']

def post_list(self, request, **kwargs):

    fileToUpload = request.FILES
    # write code to upload to amazone s3
    # see: https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html


    self.session = Session(aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_KEY_ID,
                  aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                  region_name=settings.AWS_REGION)

    client = self.session.client('s3')
    client.upload_file('zango-static','fileToUpload')


    url = "some/test/url"
    return self.create_response(request, {
        'url': url // return's public url of uploaded file 
    })
```

I searched whole documentation I couldn't find any links which describes how to do this can someone explain or provide any resource where I can find the soultion?

Comment: Where you able to get this to work?

Comment: @nadermx I wasn't able to get this work can you help me ?

Comment: Use virtual-hosted style S3 urls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56090535/795876

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm in the same situation.
Not able to find anything in the Boto3 docs beyond generate_presigned_url which is not what I need in my case since I have public readable S3 Objects.

The best I came up with is:

```py
bucket_location = boto3.client('s3').get_bucket_location(Bucket=s3_bucket_name)
object_url = "https://s3-{0}.amazonaws.com/{1}/{2}".format(
    bucket_location['LocationConstraint'],
    s3_bucket_name,
    key_name)
```

You might try posting on the [boto3 github issues list](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues) for a better solution.

Comment: Turns out I didn't need the region in the URL. `https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/my_file.jpg` worked for me.

Comment: @KimberlyW this is because the region of your asset is US-EAST1 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Comment: This answer doesn't work if the file for example has non-ascii and spaces.

Comment: this answer also doesn't work for integration tests with localstack.

Comment: Is this still the best solution?

Comment: What is meant by `key_name` ?

Answer (score 26):

The best solution I found is still to use the `generate_presigned_url`, just that the `Client.Config.signature_version` needs to be set to `botocore.UNSIGNED`.

The following returns the public link without the signing stuff.

```
config = Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED)
config.signature_version = botocore.UNSIGNED
boto3.client('s3', config=config).generate_presigned_url('get_object', ExpiresIn=0, Params={'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': key})
```

The relevant discussions on the boto3 repository are:

- https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/110
- https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/169
- https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1415

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Same keen's answer breaks if the filename is contains spaces for example, and then the heuristic of key_name = object_url with some prefix breaks.

Comment: But it has short expiration. Maximum only 7 days, and shorter for STS.

Comment: to add more clarity to the answer, it would be better to show where config does come from. Example :
`config = Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED)
url = s3_session.client('s3', config=config).generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    ExpiresIn=0,
    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
            'Key': key}
)`

Comment: Edited answer with your suggestion

Comment: Just `config = Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED)` is enough. No need for the second line

Comment: Is this still the best answer in 2022?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer indeed. 

I went with the best of both worlds: I use a normal authenticated client to put objects, and an anonymous client (as defined above) to get the URLs for these objects.

Then on the bucket permissions side, I allow anonymous reads only. (Anonymous client can't put objects or do anything else with my bucket)

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue.
Assuming you know the bucket name where you want to store your data, you can then use the following:

```py
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer

credentials = { 
    'aws_access_key_id': aws_access_key_id,
    'aws_secret_access_key': aws_secret_access_key
}

client = boto3.client('s3', 'us-west-2', **credentials)
transfer = S3Transfer(client)

transfer.upload_file('/tmp/myfile', bucket, key,
                     extra_args={'ACL': 'public-read'})

file_url = '%s/%s/%s' % (client.meta.endpoint_url, bucket, key)
```

Comment: Thank you, the extra_args in upload_file using S3Transfer is what I needed to use in conjunction when creating the client through session for custom endpoints.

Comment: how to upload file object

Comment: @pyd see this => https://stackoverflow.com/a/51758077/9183715

Comment: @NomanGul that link does not explain how to both upload an object in memory and generate a public URL from it

Answer (score 3):

Somebody who wants to build up a direct URL for the public accessible object to avoid using `generate_presigned_url` for some reason.

Please build URL with `urllib.parse.quote_plus` considering whitespace and special character issue.

- My object key: `2018-11-26 16:34:48.351890+09:00.jpg`
  **please note whitespace and ':'**
- S3 public link in aws console: `https://s3.my_region.amazonaws.com/my_bucket_name/2018-11-26+16%3A34%3A48.351890%2B09%3A00.jpg`

Below code was OK for me

```
import boto3    
s3_client = boto3.client
bucket_location = s3_client.get_bucket_location(Bucket='my_bucket_name')
url = "https://s3.{0}.amazonaws.com/{1}/{2}".format(bucket_location['LocationConstraint'], 'my_bucket_name', quote_plus('2018-11-26 16:34:48.351890+09:00.jpg')
print(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Going through the existing answers and their comments, I did the following and works well for special cases of file names like having **whitespaces**, having **special characters (ASCII)**, **corner cases. E.g. file names of the form: "key=value.txt"**

```
import boto3
import botocore

config = botocore.client.Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED)
object_url = boto3.client('s3', config=config).generate_presigned_url('get_object', ExpiresIn=0, Params={'Bucket': s3_bucket_name, 'Key': key_name})
print(object_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Django, if you use Django storages with boto3 the code below does exactly what you want:

```
default_storage.url(name=f.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an f-string for the same

```
import boto3    
#s3_client = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='sssss').client('s3')
s3_client=boto3.client('s3')
s3_bucket_name = 'xxxxx'
s3_website_URL= f"http://{s3_bucket_name}.s3-website.{s3_client.get_bucket_location(Bucket=s3_bucket_name)['LocationConstraint']}.amazonaws.com"
```