# Getting file url after upload amazon s3 python, boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm just a new with **boto3** and i can not understand how i can get URL link for file that i have just uploaded to s3 amazon.

Please clarify.

Thank you

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

data = open ('file.xlsx', 'rb')
s3.Bucket ('dimxxx1').put_object (Key='file.xlsx', Body=data)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload to Amazon S3 using Boto3 and return public url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809592/upload-to-amazon-s3-using-boto3-and-return-public-url)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the better way to upload would be:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('dimxxx1').upload_file('/tmp/file.xlsx', 'file.xlsx')
```

To obtain the URL, you can construct it from the basic elements:

```
http://s3-REGION-.amazonaws.com/BUCKET-NAME/KEY
```

For example:

```
http://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dimxxx1/file.xlsx
```

Answer (score 7):

in python3,

```
url = f"https://{bucket}.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/{folder}{file_name}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a fix for this issue to enable you get the URL of S3 file as suggested by this [link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-urls). You basically have to generate a pre-signed URL for each S3 object you wish to provide access to. See the code below:

```
import boto3

# Get the service client.
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Generate the URL to get 'key-name' from 'bucket-name'
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': '<bucket-name>',
        'Key': '<key-name>'
    }
)
```

Change the `<bucket-name>` and `<key-name>` to your S3 bucket and the name of the file that was uploaded.

Comment: thanks for your solutions. now i have a link but when i copy and past link to another browser which is not log in amazon a couldn't download file. receive error access denied. how it can be solved?

Comment: I'd warn here that pre-signed URLs have an expiration timer (max is one week) so if these need to be links that are stateful, do not use pre-signed URLs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014306/aws-s3-pre-signed-url-without-expiry-date

Answer (score 1):

This is proper sequence with python formatter:

```
url = f"https://s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/{bucket}/{folder}...N/{file_name}"
```