# Access large BDF and EDF files stored on S3 from Sagemaker by URL and read them with mne library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, mne-python

I have a bucket on [**S3**](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and a [**SageMaker**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/gs-console.html) notebook. I try to get access to rather large *BDF* and *EDF* files (1-2 GB), stored on the **S3** bucket, without uploading them to **SageMaker** volume.
I also need to access these files by URL as the *EDF* processing function [`mne.io.read_raw_edf`](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.io.read_raw_edf.html) receives the absolute path to a file as an input.

The **S3** bucket is in the same region as the **Sagemaker Notebook Instance**. The IAM role associated with the notebook instance is given permission to access the **S3** bucket.

First, I tried to use the approach from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264656/load-s3-data-into-aws-sagemaker-notebook), that describes how to read `.csv` files. Although in my case it worked well with `.csv` files, it failed with `.edf` ones.

```
import pandas as pd
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

role = get_execution_role()

bucket='my-bucket'
key = 'train.edf'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, key)

mne.io.read_raw_edf(data_location)
```

When I execute this code, I receive the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/s3:/my-bucket/train.edf'
```

Here I face a path stacking that was not done by me. I don't quite understand why `pd.read_csv` read paths normally, unlike `mne.io.read_raw_edf`, which seems to stack the local path and the server one.

Then I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698521/6936382) to a very similar question but faced a very similar problem with the stacked paths.

```
import boto3

bucket_location = boto3.client('s3').get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket)
object_url = "https://s3-{0}.amazonaws.com/{1}/{2}".format(
    bucket_location['LocationConstraint'],
    bucket,
    key)
object_url
```

```
'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/train.edf'
```

Here we can see that the path is stored normally.

```
mne.io.read_raw_edf(object_url)
```

When I execute this code, I receive the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/https:/s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/train.edf'
```

`mne.io.read_raw_edf` performs the weird stacking again.

At last, I tried to follow the approach described in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/working-with-amazon-s3-buckets-with-boto3-785252ea22e0).

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3", 
                  region_name='us-west-2', 
                  aws_access_key_id='access_key_id', 
                  aws_secret_access_key='secret_access_key')

share_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod="get_object", 
                                      ExpiresIn=3600,
                                      Params={"Bucket": bucket, "Key": key})
share_url
```

```
'https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/train.edf?AWSAccessKeyId=access_key_id&Signature=signature&Expires=1616777253'
```

The path seems to be normal again.

```
mne.io.read_raw_edf(share_url)
```

```
NotImplementedError: Only EDF files are supported by read_raw_edf, got edf?awsaccesskeyid=access_key_id&
signature=signature&expires=1616777253
```

But here I got another weird `mne.io.read_raw_edf` behavior. No more stacking but the path was cropped.

I assume that it could be `mne.io.read_raw_edf` problem itself, but I have never faced anything like this outside **Amazon** products.

Does it make sense to get access to the *BDF* and *EDF* files by URLs or is it better to upload the files to the **SageMaker** volume? I apologize if this question seems naive. I've already spent a couple of days solving this problem, but I need to sort it out as soon as possible as **Amazon** takes money for every hour when the notebook is active.

Comment: Checking the MNE source, it looks like they read raw files by running `input_fname = os.path.abspath(input_fname)`, so I don't think they support loading remote data. Your only option might be to download the file to the SageMaker hard drive and then read it locally