# directly uploading csv file from url to s3 bucket

Tags: python, api, python-requests

How can I upload a csv file that has been retrieved from url to s3 bucket using python?
P.S. the csv file has not been downloaded to the system but in fact it needs to be automated where the csv file is directly uploaded in s3.

Comment: This will probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346065/upload-image-available-at-public-url-to-s3-using-boto

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload image available at public URL to S3 using boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346065/upload-image-available-at-public-url-to-s3-using-boto)