# Handle gzipped or bzip2ed downloads without keeping compressed data

Tags: python, gzip, urllib2, bzip2

I'd like to download a compressed file (either in gzip or bzip2), decompress it and analyze its contents (it's a CSV-like file with lots of data, I calculate sums, averages and such for certain columns) *while* the download happens (so that I can show partial results before the download ends). The file is big (4GB), decompressed stream is even bigger, so I don't want to keep the whole compressed file on disk or in memory.

I thought it will be possible to combine python's gzip or bz2 implementations with urllib2:

```
data_stream = csv.reader(
                  gzip.GzipFile(
                      fileobj=urllib2.urlopen('http://…/somefile.gz')),
                  delimiter='\t')
```

…but it seems that urlopen's file is not file-like enough for GzipFile. I get a traceback after trying to read from such a stream:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 450, in readline
    c = self.read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 256, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 283, in _read
    pos = self.fileobj.tell()   # Save current position
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'tell'
```

BZ2 module is even worse—it doesn't allow passing a file object at all.

After looking for some answers, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4204604/42610). The answer works by basically storing the whole compressed file in memory, which is unfeasible for me.

What can I do?

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732726/322909).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [zlib in python](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/zlib.html).  `zlib.decompressobj` will create an object that can be fed gzip compressed data piecemeal, and spit out the available uncompressed data using the `decompress` method on the object.  You need to set `wbits` to 31 to decode the gzip format.  15 will decode the zlib format.

Comment: Yeah, but then I'll need a wrapper object to make it look like an iterable for csv.reader, right? Is there anything that does this part?

Comment: That's the easy part.  The heavy lifting has been done for you by zlib.